# RSVP.js - Multiple asynchronous function calls on array

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, promise, rsvp.js

I have a result from a REST call that contains a list of files. Each file has properties that I have to extract and place in a new array. This is straightforward and is easily done with a simple loop. Three of the properties I need to extract are accessible in a direct way, while three other properties are of HATEOAS type, which in other words mean that for each file in the result, I have to make three other asynchronous calls to retrieve it's values.

My first instinct was to use `RSVP.all()` to process my promises and to map the items in the new array to the corresponding properties in the original list of files using `map`, but I cannot figure out how to achieve this.

I want to achieve something like below, but I have no idea how I can get the index of the current mapped item in `itemList`, to include the correct file from `fileList`. How can I do this?

On a sidenote, if I use `RSVP.all()` the wrong way I'm happy to receive tips!

```
function createItemList(fileList) {
    var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var itemList = [];

        //For each file in fileList, get the directly accessible properties
        //and push it to a new array
        for (var i = 0, file; file = fileList[i]; i++) {
            currentItem.Name = file.Name;
            currentItem.LastModified = new Date(file.TimeLastModified).format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
            currentItem.Version = file.MajorVersion + "." + file.MinorVersion;

            itemList.push(currentItem);
        }

        //This is where it starts to get messy...
        //I want to map each item in the new itemlist to the corresponding properties
        //in the fileList. If I can include the corresponding file somehow, I could set the
        //data in the method 'getModifiedBy' and similar. I believe this should work,
        //but I have no idea how I can achieve this.
        var modifiedBy = itemList.map(function(item) {
            return getModifiedBy(item, fileList[INDEX]);
        });

        var checkedOutBy = itemList.map(function (item) {
            return getCheckedOutBy(item, fileList[INDEX]);
        });

        var eventDate = itemList.map(function (item) {
            return getEventDate(item, fileList[INDEX]);
        });

        var promises = {
            promisesModifiedBy: modifiedBy,
            promisesCheckedOutBy: checkedOutBy,
            promisesEventDate: eventDate
        };

        RSVP.all(promises)
            .then(function() {
            resolve(itemList);
        });
    });
    return promise;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use only a single map over the `itemlist` that returns a Promise for your 3-property-object. Use a dedicated helper function for single items.

Btw, with `new RSVP.Promise` you're using the [deferred antipattern](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572) while there's absolutely no reason - `RSVP.all()` already returns you the result promise.

```
function createItemList(fileList) {
    return RSVP.all(fileList.map(createItem));
}
function createItem(file) {
    // get the directly accessible properties
    var currentItem = {}; 
    currentItem.Name = file.Name;
    currentItem.LastModified = new Date(file.TimeLastModified).format("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss");
    currentItem.Version = file.MajorVersion + "." + file.MinorVersion;

    return RSVP.hash({
        modifiedBy: getModifiedBy(currentItem, file),
        checkedOutBy: getCheckedOutBy(currentItem, file)
        eventDate: getEventDate(currentItem, file)
    }).then(function(asyncprops) {
        // somehow mix the asyncprops with the currentItem
        return item; // into a result item
    });
}
```

Comment: This works exactly how I want it to work, though, I'm having a hard time really understanding what is going on, even when debugging! I guess I'll have to read up on promises. Also, thank you for pointing out the use of the deferred antipattern! I was not at all aware of that!